# LoadError causing Server not to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### Can anybody explain this for me?

```
$ rails s
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Sam/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/First With Book/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Its my first rails program and I was following a [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) which [changed the gemfile](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#code-gemfile_sqlite_version) but it hasn't worked, I guess I haven't installed something, I'm running gems 2.0.3 and rails 4.0.0 and with ruby I get this:

```
$ ruby  -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800920/error-no-such-file-to-load-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror?rq=1)

download the required executable and the dll from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html extract to your ruby's bin (c:\Ruby200\bin)

Comment: Sorry that hasn't worked. I installed it and got the message from the ruby sqlite3 guys and restarted everything and made a new project but got the same response. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try these solutions [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514449/rails-4-0rc1-app-not-running-due-to-missing-sqlite3-gem?rq=1) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: In addition I suggest you switch to a OS X or Linux for development, it will ease a lot of headaches that you encounter with Windows. (I'm telling from trying to stick with Windows for quite some time). If you need Windows you can install Virtual Box and use a distro on it.

Comment: I've just realised that after installing the parts mentioned above, it created a new folder called `C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3` should i be using this?