# Rails 4 fails on sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I get this error when I run a new empty rails (4.0) site:

```
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.
```

I have a valid sqlite3 gem built with the devkit.  I made a dumb test for that:

```
w:...> ruby   hello.rb
hello world
test.db is done.
```

Which also creates an empty database, called "test.db" as shown below.  Simple ruby script:

```
  require "sqlite3"

  puts "hello world"

  # Open a database
  db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"

  puts "test.db is done."
```

My conclusion is that the **sqlite3** gem is working OK and that there's something amiss inside rails some place.  Suggestions or explanations welcome.

Bit of an update following the comment about **Gemfile**:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]
```

In addition, I used the **bundle show** command, and I find this *strange*:

```
w:...> bundle show sqlite3
Could not find gem 'sqlite3'.
Did you mean sqlite3?
```

When I do a **bundle install** the output list does not include  **sqlite3**.  I should add the Gemfile and everything else was generated right out of the box by a "**rails new train**" command (project name, '*train*' of course).

Environment is an install of Ruby v2, Rails v4 on Windows 7 64-bit PC.  I have PIK to manage different versions of ruby.  Suggestions welcome, thanks in advance, Will.

Everything is/should be fresh-out-of-the-box Rails 4/Ruby 2 configuration.  I'm adding the server's stack dump also, since in theory a fresh install *should be working*.

```
Gem::LoadError (Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.):
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:55:in `resolve_hash_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railtie.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:50:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__398267657__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  B:/lang/ruby/v02.00/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  B:/lang/ruby/v02.00/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  B:/lang/ruby/v02.00/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bits of news to report.  I was passed an explanation for this on the PIK mailing list:

> [**[Luis Lavena](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/109)**] You don't indicate which version of Ruby 2.0 are you using (the exact output of "ruby -v"), but I will assume is x64 bit, correct?
>
> If that is the case, then you're affected by a bug in Bundler. The same was reported here:

- https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/109

Yes, the problem is happening with Ruby v2 64-bit

```
 w:...> ruby -v
 ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [x64-mingw32]
 
 w:...> bundle -v
 Bundler version 1.3.5
```

Reading the [sparklemotion](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/109) post the error lies with Bundler.  To be fathomed I guess.

On the plus side.  I used Rails 4 with Ruby 2 to make the rails project and can run the server to use SQLite3 using JRuby by changing the Gemfile to use the jdbc driver, as shown:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  #  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
end
```

It almost looks like Bundler has a thing against SQLite3 doesn't it?

One last thing.  The Sqlite3 gem build OK with Ruby v2 and works, as demonstrated with my toy test program.  Since it is just a Gem ... the Bundler problem *may* pop-up for some other gems -- Be alert, probably best to upgrade as soon as you see the problem:

```
w:...> ruby -S gem update bundler --prerelease
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.4.0.rc.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.4.0.rc.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.4.0.rc.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.4.0.rc.1
Installing darkfish documentation for bundler-1.4.0.rc.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 9 seconds
Gems updated: bundler
```

Just check the list

```
w:...> bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
    :
  * sprockets (2.10.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  * thor (0.18.1)
    :
```

Works a treat!

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Dou you have:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

or something like this

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]
```

in your Gemfile?

Comment: Tried that -- no change.  I have updated the question information.