# Windows/Ruby/Rails install --- .cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-8, sqlite

Ruby 2.1.3p242 <2014-09-19 revision 47630> [x64-mingw32]
Rails 4.2.0.beta2

I'm running windows 8 on a 64 bit system. I have been using c9 (cloud hosted ubuntu) but want to start using RubyMine IDE on my pc to make everything faster but it's posing some problems.

I've tried pretty much every recommended way including this one:
[How do I install sqlite3 for Ruby on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows)

but I'm still getting the same error message. You help is much appreciated! Please let me know if you have any questions for me.

Full Error message when I run $rails s:

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/aynulhabib-habib-framework-aca42deddccd/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Sites/aynulhabib-habib-framework-aca42deddccd/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/aynulhabib-habib-framework-aca42deddccd/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that binary sqlite3 gem do not include pre-compiled versions for Ruby 2.1.3

This is mentioned in the sqlite3-ruby mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlite3-ruby/cNqvONJmocU/C0Rdg6ZxhV4J).

Comment: ah got it, so I need to switch to ruby 2.0, thanks for your help!

Comment: @AynulHabib FYI, gem sqlite3 version 1.3.10 was released last night and includes support for 2.1 :)

Answer (score 10):

fortunately, you don't have to switch to ruby 2.0
there is a solution to this issue, after endless trying...

https://github.com/hwding/sqlite3-ruby-win

---

## Steps

#### Pre

- `gem uninstall sqlite3 --all`

#### Source

- Download the latest sqlite3-ruby, https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby
- unzip the package

#### Build

- run command-line in the extracted dir
- make sure you have your C compiler installed and added to PATH
- `gem install bundler`
- `bundle install`
- `rake native gem`
- you'll find a dir named 'pkg' generated

#### Install

- enter dir 'pkg'
- `gem install --local sqlite3-xxx.gem` ('xxx' is version code)

#### Check

- `irb`
- `require 'sqlite3'`

Comment: This is what finally made it! Thanks! This shoud be the accepted answer.

Comment: unfortunately getting this : rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass   while executing rake native gem

Comment: It does not create 'pkg' directory

Answer (score 1):

In the folder of your project open terminal and execute:

> bundle update sqlite3
>
> bundle update nokogiri

I hope i have helped you ;)

EDIT:

- i always recommend using linux/mac for ruby, because some gems may get problematic, because of compiling errors with `c`
- always use bundle to manage your gems, it is much easier*, 
  you can install it by:

  - `gem install bundler`
  - `bundle install` - will install all the gems in your `Gemfile`
  - the last `bundler` version is not compatible withe ruby bellow 2.3, so use `gem install bundler -v 1.16.4`

Answer (score 0):

If you have extracted "exe"s and "dll"s from [Sqlite download link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to Ruby's bin folder and still have this problem. Try this:

`bundle update`

`gem uninstall sqlite3`

Given a choice between multiple versions of sqlite3,  choose last option 'All versions'. Enter last number here

> Select gem to uninstall:
>   1. sqlite3-1.3.13
>   2. sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32
>   3. All versions
>   >`3`
>   .
>   .
>   If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
>   Continue with Uninstall? [yN]
>   >
>   `y`

`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby`

`rails s`

This should work.

Read through this [link](http://wikiprogramming.org/linux/ruby-2-5-1-windows-fix-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3_native-loaderror/) for more explanation if above works for you.