# cannot load such file sqlite3 - Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am following rails tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app and am running into an error when I run this `$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`

Here is the error:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x86-mingw32/l
ib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (L
oadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-
x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'rescue in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-
x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in 'each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in 'block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in 'each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in 'require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in 'require'
        from c:/sites/workspace/toy_app/config/application.rb:7:in '<top (requir
ed)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in 'require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in 'require_application_and_environmen
t!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in 'generate_or_destroy'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in 'generate'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in '<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in 'require'
        from bin/rails:4:in '<main>'
```

I am using Windows 8.  I am using Gitbash.  I installed ruby and rails from the install rails website.  When I type ruby -v I get `ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]`

I tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails?lq=1) but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're sure you have sqlite installed on your machine? I'm not sure if Rails automatically installs that when you download it or not.

Comment: When I type `sqlite --version` I get `sh.exe": sqlite: command not found`.  How do I install it?

Comment: Double-check that you added `gem 'gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'` under `group :development, :test` in your Gemfile (and that you ran `bundle install --without production`).

Comment: Yup its there and I ran bundle install --without production.  I had run bundle install and forgot the --without production, but just ran it again with it.

Comment: Just ran these commands in irb not sure if it helps: `irb(main):001:0> require 'sqlite3'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> SQLite3::SQLITE_VERSION
=> "3.8.7.1"
irb(main):003:0> exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636471/windows-ruby-rails-install-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native) post solves my problem. I need to use sqlite 1.3.10 which includes support for Ruby 2.1. Sqlite 1.3.9 does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails Installer for windows it will install everything that you will need.

You can get Rails Installer from: http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: This is what I used to install everything.  I am going to uninstall and reinstall and see what happens.

Comment: Just reinstalled and still encountering the same problem.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: When I make that change I get another error here is a snippet of the error `c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 'require': Could not load 'active_record/conn
ection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.
yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' o
r 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0):

Try, on your project terminal:

> bundle update sqlite3
>
> bundle update nokogiri

I hope i have helped you ;)