# Ruby install gem offline in Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to install some Ruby gems in Windows in the offline-mode (without internet). I have gem files downloaded from the other PC.

As long as the gem does not require specific options (with `--`), I just execute `gem install somegem --local` and everything is fine.

But if the gem does require those options, there is a trouble. For example, I want to install `sqlite3-1.3.10.gem`:

```
gem install sqlite3 --local -- --with-sqlite3-dir="c:\programs\sqlite"
```

This returns me an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
invalid option: --with-sqlite3-dir=c:\programs\sqlite
```

What is wrong?

- ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
- Rails 4.2.2

Comment: --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/programs/sqlite --with-sqlite3-include=C:/programs/sqlite are you sure C:/programs/sqlite exists? Then try withour double -- --

Comment: @user3344236 it's not about `sqlite`, I get error `invalid option` for *any gem* install with specific options. But I tried your options - same result.

Comment: I use this kind of -- --:  gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-lib=c:/

Comment: @user3344236 it doesn't matter, error is the same for any other gem with any other options after `--`

Comment: I don't mind to ask anyway: what versions have you for gem,  ruby, rails (-v) ? Have multiple installs, old one present? for me it sounds like mismatching versions. And how you manage to put dependencies at work offline?

Comment: @user3344236 yeah, forgot to mention this. Updated the post.

Comment: @user3344236 no other installs of Ruby, this is the one and only.

Comment: Try putting everything after the `--` in quotes, that has been necessary for me in the past.

Comment: @simonwo same result, unfortunately. I also removed `--` but that did not help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the reason. I ran all commands in Windows `PowerShell`.

Now I tried to do it in usual `cmd.exe` - and it just worked.

Just for a case here is how I installed `sqlite3.gem`: followed instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023062 and executed command:

```
gem install sqlite3-1.3.10.gem --local --platform=ruby -- '--with-sqlite3-dir="c:/programs/sqlite" --with-sqlite3-lib="c:/programs/sqlite/.libs" --with-sqlite3-include="c:/programs/sqlite"'
```

Thank you for comments, they helped to correct the command.