# How to fix 'rails generate scaffold' error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed a book and typed:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I got:

```
display Error:
Could not find gem 'turbolinks (~> 5) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources >listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I still get an error after I type `bundle install`.

[image]

I have installed sqlite3 on the machine.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle install`? Here's another question on the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101183/could-not-find-gem-turbolinks-source-5

Comment: `bundle install` have not been executed correctly. What interactions do you get?

Comment: Do you have SQLite3 installed on your machine?