# Ruby on Rails can't reach server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I'm trying to learn ruby on rails but can't manage to have the server working. I've been following 2 tutorials and, every time I come across the server section, for some reason I can't let it work.

First tutorial I tried was the one that can be found at http://installrails.com/

I follow every step and when I get to type ***$ rails server*** I get the error explained here [Could not find gem 'turbolinks-source (~> 5)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101183/could-not-find-gem-turbolinks-source-5)

Since I could get it solved, I tried with the IFTTT tutorial with no better results since after following their instruction and adding the ***tzinfo-data*** gem that was apparently missing from their script, I get this log

```
[2019-06-08 19:12:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2019-06-08 19:12:03] INFO  ruby 2.3.3 (2016-11-21) [i386-mingw32]
[2019-06-08 19:12:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4504 port=3000
```

but still I can't reach the address they suggest (http://0.0.0.0:3000/).

It's pretty obvious to me that I'm missing something, but I really can't wrap my mind around it.

Should it help, 
ruby version is 2.3.3p222 and rails one is 5.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running a Ruby on Rails application on a local machine the following two URL should work:

- http://localhost:3000 or
- http://127.0.0.1:3000

Btw: `0.0.0.0` basically means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine.

Comment: Now if you could also help with me not feeling like a moron

Answer (score 1):

I friendly suggest you follow official rails guides here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

they are well written and designated to learn rails. You will find these guides helpful.