# NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass when running "rake native gem"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Alright, so I am having trouble creating a rails server. When I create one, and run `bundle install`, it is fine. Once I type in `rails server`, I get that dreaded error of missing file: sqlite3/sqlite3_native. I am quite aware that there is a question on this site about that specific problem, and when trying to follow the instructions for installing the sqlite3 gem, one of the steps is to do `rake native gem`, Which ends up giving me the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass". I have a C,C++, and Java compiler added to cmd. Please help me.

Note: I am currently on Ruby 2.5.1-1, and I have rails 5.2.0 installed.

Comment: Are you using windows os?

Comment: Yes. I am currently running Windows 10 pro edition, 64 bit.

Comment: something is missing in installation part.

Comment: what could be missing from it?

Comment: Have you already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows)?