# Rails new app_name fails due to Sqlite3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, bundler

On Windows 10 64bit

Using Railsinstaller I installed the bundler necessary to build my App.

After the installation I checked the versions of:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.2

$ gem -v
2.5.2

$ bundler -v
Bundler version 2.0.1

$ sqlite3 --version
3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56 2ab564bf9655b7c7b97ab85cafc8a48329b27f93
```

Then I started `rails new my_app_name` which ended with these errors:

**mkmf.log**

```
package configuration for sqlite3 is not found
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:21: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

And **gem_make.out**

```
current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190214-3564-1lpwzs0.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I am total beginner with Ruby and this is my first attempt to create app so I can experiment. It seems to me that the problem is related with the Sqlite3 version. I tried to update it via `gem` and `bundle` but I got error again.

Comment: Not a windows user myself, this might help you though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and these are the two solutions I found.
1* After the bundle install fail to enter on the project folder and modify the Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3',  '1.3.11'
```

this line change it by some of these 3 below

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby"

gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"

gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

It only works if you've installed first Ruby Devkit or RubyInstaller and later Rails Installer, otherwise Rails Installer Ruby folder will be choosed by system as "ruby folder"

2* you'll have to uninstall RailsInstaller and remove the remaining folder(if you don't remove manually the folder after uninstaller ends, when you execute gem command it'll says "RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin" folder not found)
Ok, after it install rails by command line

```
gem install rails
```

And install by command line MinGW

```
C:\Sites>ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
```

Download the gem file from https://rubygems.org/ and save it locally and install from file

```
gem install --local C:\sqlite3-1.4.0.gem
```

This second solution works globally so you've to run it only once and the next time you execute `rails new blog` the issue with sqlite won't appear again. Just make sure to execute it on the Sites folder not inside any project or it'll work only for that project.

If any of these works for you please feel free to try one of the methods I mention here https://mycodeissuesandfixes.blogspot.com/2019/02/ruby-on-rails-issue-about-sqlite-3-gem.html , I've tried to find a solution for more than a week to this.

Good Luck!! Hope it helps you