# I can't run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

how's going?
I trying to create my first application with Ruby on Rails, I can create the project but I can't run the server.
My OS is Windows.
I installed Node, Yarn, Ruby, Rails, Sqlite3.
This message appears when I try to run "rails s"

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I run the command "bundle install", "bundle update" and doesn't work. This message appears when I run "bundle install":

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

When I verify the version of sqlite3:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9JGW.png)
I tried editing Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.2'
```

And tried install this way:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

I tried this steps too:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAseoJeNG8I

I follow the recommendation in the documentation for windows users and run "bin/rails s" on Bash, but still the same problem.
I read other answers here to similar questions but did not help me, for this I ask with this.
If something was a miss to you understand the problem please tell me and I provide the information.
Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The above Error occurred because `sqlite3` is not installed on your system.

**Step1:-** First, install the `sqlite3` on your system by following the steps mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows)

**Step2:-** Run `bundle install`

Comment: When I verify the version this appears: 3.37.0 2021-11-27 14:13:22 bd41822c7424d393a30e92ff6cb254d25c26769889c1499a18a0b9339f5d6c8a. I put sqlite3 dll/exe in bin folder how described in the question that you mention. I put the version in gemfile '1.4.1' doesn't work too. Just steps mention by use autoconfig that I didn't because I don't know how compile .configure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting `gemfile.lock`? Try delete and after that again type `bundle install`

Comment: I search in my project and there aren't gemfile.lock only gemfile. Would a good idea reinstall the Rails?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea. 
As I know gemfile.lock is mandatory because it's shows us all of ours installed gems. Try it and give us a feedback

Comment: Now generated gemfile.lock. But when I try run `rails s` this message appears **cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)**

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails) try solve problem like in this link.